# show results with biggest count mysql

Tags: mysql, count

I need to show user with the most comments. I have two tables:

Table: **Users**

```
ID   |  USERNAME   |    EMAIL
------------------------------
1    |   USER01    |   EMAIL01
2    |   USER02    |   EMAIL02
3    |   USER03    |   EMAIL03
4    |   USER04    |   EMAIL04
```

Table: **Comments**

```
ID   |  AUTHOR     |    COMMENT
----------------------------------
1    |   USER01    |   COMMENT...
2    |   USER02    |   COMMENT...
3    |   USER01    |   COMMENT...
4    |   USER03    |   COMMENT...
```

In this example the `user01` have the most comments, but lets say I have to result them all with count of comments they have. And also in result I have to show users email which is stored in Users table.

How can I count and at same time check in both tables to return result? Or should I first get user info and then count ?

Comment: Do show us, what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select username,email,count(*) as cnt 
from users, comments 
where author = username 
 group by username
 order by cnt desc
 limit 1
```

Answer (score 3):

this query below handles duplicate rows having the most number of comments,

```
SELECT  a.userName
FROM    Users a
        INNER JOIN Comments b
            ON a.username = b.author
GROUP BY    a.userName
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(totalCount)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT author, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    comments
            GROUP BY author
        ) a
    )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f34e0/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with duplicate*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aa09/1)

but if you want not to handle that, it can be simply done by using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT  a.userName, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    Users a
        INNER JOIN Comments b
            ON a.username = b.author
GROUP BY    a.userName
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f34e0/2)

Comment: +1 . . . Using proper join syntax is definitely worth an upvote.